# Couldn't connect socket: [111] Connection refused

Tags: php, sockets, gps

I am trying to develop GPS tracking system using PHP. I have GPS Tracking devices installed on vehicles and I can able to set the IP Address and Port through SMS. SO that device will send the data to the given server port.My Ideal is, using PHP Socket I will listen the socket and store it into MySQL database. Later I can do whatever I want

The problem now is I not able to receive message from device. Please look into my code first

SERVER SIDE SOCKET CODE: (server.php)

```
<?php
$_SOCKET = "166.62.10.183";
$_PORT   = 5544;

if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket created \n";

// Bind the source address
if( !socket_bind($sock, $_SOCKET , $_PORT) )
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not bind socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket bind OK \n";

if(!socket_listen ($sock , 10))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not listen on socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket listen OK \n";
echo "Listening on \n SOCKET: ".$_SOCKET."\n PORT: ".$_PORT."\n";
echo "Waiting for incoming connections... \n";

//start loop to listen for incoming connections
while (true) 
{
    //Accept incoming connection - This is a blocking call
    $client =  socket_accept($sock);

    //display information about the client who is connected
    if(socket_getpeername($client , $address , $port))
    {
        echo "Client $address : $port is now connected to us. \n";
    }

    //read data from the incoming socket
    $input = socket_read($client, 1024000);

    $response = "OK .. $input";
    echo $response;
}
?>
```

CLIENT SIDE TEST CODE: (client.php)

```
<?php

//Creating a Socket
if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}
echo "1:: ---- Socket Created </br><br>";


//Connecting to Server
if(!socket_connect($sock, "166.62.10.183", 5544)){
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    die("Couldn't connect socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg </br>");
}
echo "2:: ---- Connection Established </br></br>";

//Send message to Server
$message = "Message from Web\r\n";
if(!socket_send($sock, $message, strlen($message), 0 )){
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    die("Couldn't not send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg </br>");
}
echo "3:: ---- Message sent </br></br>";
// ?>
```

When I am running the client.php code from the same server, I can able to see message in server.php (I running through SSH "php server.php"). When I am running code from any other server I am seeing following error message

> 1:: ---- Socket Created
>
> Couldn't connect socket: [111] Connection refused

I think because of this, I can't able to receive message from GPS Device. Guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you have a firewall that might be blocking the connections?  Why are you specifying protocol as `0`? Don't you want `SOL_TCP`?

Comment: I check and I was able to telnet to port 22 on your server but not on 5544, which means it is not enabled for external access. Depending on whether your cloud provider has firewall or your machine has firewall enabled, you need to enable port 5544 for external access

Comment: Thanks @Don'tPanic . I tried with all available protocols. But still its not working. I have contacted hosting provider and they have opened the port. Still no luck

Comment: @TarunLalwani are you mentioning about inbound port. My Hosting provider enabled only outgoing port.

Comment: @Kalaivanan, outgoing doesn't matter here. Then incoming port will matter. Your client will connect on the incoming port, so it needs to be open. And telnet from external machine should work when your server is running, else nothing externally can connect

Comment: @Kalaivanan as tarun said you have to enable inbound port. I have mentioned few cods below use them to test for connection. also use already open port like 80 just to verify that is the issue.

Comment: @Kalaivanan also easiest to try is `telnet <ip-addr> <port>` from server  and and telent on the port outside the network

Answer (score 1):

Hi if the ip you have mentioned is correct then I can see only ftp http portes open and sip port.

use

```
nmap <ip-addr>
```

to check open port.
or you can test using netcat

```
nc <ip-addr> <port>
      OR
nc -v -w 1 <ip-addr> -z <port>
```

these tools help you debug.
and like mentioned in comment it may also be firewall issue. to verify it you can temporary change listening port to 80. as it is open as far as I can see.
if that also fails. we may look into php code for more details. please provide your observation to above commands.
check them form same network using private ip (e.g. 192.168.1.x) and out side network using public ip (e.g. 166.62.10.183) . see if you see different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the issue is with the firewall as [@Don't Panic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700838/couldnt-connect-socket-111-connection-refused#comment80696875_46700838) and [@Tarun Lalwani](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700838/couldnt-connect-socket-111-connection-refused#comment80703570_46700838) have said - make sure if you're wanting to connect on a particular port that the server has that port open to accept inbound connections.

Also, why are you trying to write your own socket server from scratch? There are [plenty of PHP socket libraries out there to make your life easier](https://libraries.io/search?keywords=Socket&languages=PHP) - you might want to look at [ReactPHP](https://reactphp.org/) and [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/).

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting provider won't open ports, you may be able to use a proxy configuration.  It's easier in nginx but can also be done in apache.  If you are using AWS (or any cloud provider) you will need to configure open ports or proxy through the ones that are open.

I agree with @Devidas, use nmap to see what ports are open.

Your code also doesn't indicate an event loop, which will be needed to daemonize.  You should write it in this style (which only takes about 100 lines of code for a simple one), or use one of the many that exist, for instance php pear or the ones mentioned above.  This would apply to both client and server, of course.

It would be a hopeful long-shot that the client and server connect at the same moment over WAN the way you have it written!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers, From past two days work I got to know that the server is not setup correctly to receive information from external device. Firewall is blocking the incoming connection. No shared hosting/could hosting service providers is ready to open the port. They telling, for security reasons they will not open the port for outbound connection. Finally the same code working well with Dedicated server with after opening the port for inbound and outbound connection